# Strings and structures in c

Tags: c

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

struct s 
{
  char *st;
  struct s *sp; 
};

struct s *p1,*p2;
void swap(struct s *p1,struct s *p2);

int main()
{
    int i;
    struct s *p[3];
    static struct s a[]={
        {"abc",a+1},{"def",a+2},{"ghi",a}
    };
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
     p[i]=a[i].sp;
    }
    swap(*p,a);
    printf("%s %s %s\n",p[0]->st,(*p)->st,(*p)->sp->st);
    return 0;
}
void swap(struct s *p1,struct s *p2)
{
    char *temp;
    temp = p1->st;
    p1->st = p2->st;
    p2->st = temp;
}
```

This program outputs as abc,abc,ghi. My doubt is what does p[0]->st,(*p)->st,(*p)->sp->st outputs.we havent intialised st with abc or ghi.How does it outputs the string?

Comment: p[0] and *p are essentially the same thing.

Comment: What do you mean, you haven't initialized `st`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We havent intialised st with abc or ghi. How does it outputs the
>   string?

The value of the `st` member for each structure in the statically allocated array `a` is actually initialized through an initialization list.  Writing

```
static struct s a[]={
    {"abc",a+1},{"def",a+2},{"ghi",a}
};
```

has the same effective meaning after its execution as writing the following:

```
static struct s a[3];
a[0].st = "abc";
a[0].sp = a+1;
a[1].st = "def";
a[1].sp = a+2;
a[2].st = "ghi";
a[2].sp = a;
```

And what's effectively happened after both methods of initialization is you have a statically-allocated circular linked list of `struct s`, where the data-members of each node in the list (the `st` member) is pointing to a string literal like "abc", "def", etc.  The `sp` data member is pointing to the next node in the linked list.

Comment: This answers it. If I wasn't out of votes, I would upvote you.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't analysed all the statements, but assignment to `->st` and `->sp` happens here:

```
static struct s a[]={
    {"abc",a+1},{"def",a+2},{"ghi",a}
};
```

the rest are games with pointers so the output is what you see. So, say:

1. the `a` array is created and initialized;
2. in the for loop the `p` array is also initialized;
3. noticing that `sp` recursively points to `struct s` instances, `p` and `a` have the same structure;
4. each elements of `p` is made point to a `struct s` instance taken from one of the elements of `a`.

Comment: Yeah.. a+2 gets assigned to sp so moving to the 3rd location of a[] gives the st as "ghi".Thanks sergio.

Comment: @Code Monkey:`a + n` is an array position, as you say; the fact is that `struct s` is a recursive structure, and its `sp` member is made point to another `struct s` inside of the same array; actually, I don't see any assignment to `sp` in the loop... `sp` value is assigned to p...

Comment: @sergio: I meant, `p[i]=a[i].sp;` - oops.